# Margin-bottom not working correctly in responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this odd problem in using margin-bottom in a class for responsive design. For example

**HTML**

```
<div class="space-bottom">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque commodo sollicitudin molestie. In lacus purus, posuere non lacus eu, pharetra suscipit arcu.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.space-bottom{margin-bottom: 10px}
```

The class "space-bottom" with a margin bottom of 10px will not work in mobile device. Even if i insert it in a Media Query which is weird. But when i change the "class" into "ID"

**HTML**

```
<div id="space-bottom">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque commodo sollicitudin molestie. In lacus purus, posuere non lacus eu, pharetra suscipit arcu.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#id space-bottom{margin-bottom: 10px}
```

It seems to work. I don't even need to insert the attribute inside a Media Query

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your CSS in the first example; what you may be noticing is that the margins for the `<p>` element and the `<div>` are collapsing, based on the browser's default margin for `<p>`.

See [Mozilla Developer Network's page on collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) for more information on this feature.

Also, the CSS in your second example is incorrect; that should be selecting a `<space-bottom>` element with id `id`. Why it works, or seems to work, is a mystery to me.